# Trying to access Model data from a JavaScript function after the page has been rendered NodeJS EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This is my first NodeJS application so this may be a beginner question. I'm using [Ejs](https://ejs.co/) to build the UI and I'm sending a model with data that I'm displaying in a table.

I'm trying to access this model's data in a JavaScript function to save myself another call to the database but I can't seem to get it right.

```
<h1 class="in-line">Phone Log (<%= model.length %>)</h1>
<p id="pPhoneValue" class="in-line right-element">R -------</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary in-line right-element" onclick="valueSearch(model)">View</button>
<input class="in-line right-element" type="number"  id="iPhoneID" name="iPhoneID" placeholder="Enter Phone ID">
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Phone ID</th>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Model</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% for( const phone of model) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= phone.ID %></td>
                    <td><%= phone.Make %></td>
                    <td><%= phone.Model %></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript function but right now it's just displaying the passed data for those interested.

```
function valueSearch(Data){
    console.log(Data);
}
```

Currently, when I push the button I get "Model is not defined".

Here is the code that calls and renders the page from NodeJs:

```
app.get("/view", (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        const request = new sql.Request();
        const getAllQuery = "SELECT * FROM Phone_Information ORDER BY PhoneID";
        request.query(getAllQuery, function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
            sql.close();
            res.render("viewLog", { model: result.recordset });
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey OP it'd be nice if you can post the nodejs as it might be helpful. 
I don't know how your program works but with ejs do:

```
valueSearch(<%=model%>)
```

You always need the `<%%>` if you want to stand a variable as the html won't understand what variable you're talking about

edit: I tried and it doesn't work, maybe it's how ejs interacts with html or I am missing something but one way you can actually make it defined is:

```
let model = document.querySelectorAll('#model').innerText
```

ejs file:

```
<div id = "model" hidden><%= model %></div>
```

Comment: Hi there, I will update the question to include the NodeJs code, I wasn't sure if it was needed because i saw this as a front end issue.

I did however already try the <%= %> and it threw an error saying it Could not find matching close tag for "<%="

Comment: if doesn't say 'varname is not defined' you might be on the right track (or it's the next error). If it says 'cannot find closing tag for:...' it means it's a syntax error. Install EJS lint and then run the command ejslint <filename>  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-lint

Comment: Thanks for the EJS Lint tip. So if i use onclick="valueSearch(<% model %>)" then i get 'undefined', so it does seem to work but the value isn't there. If i use onclick="valueSearch(<%= model %>)" then i get the Unexpected identifier error. Not sure if that helps

Comment: yeah I tried and it doesn't work. Maybe it's how ejs interacts with the javascript in html but it doesn't work. Try the new method i edited in the answer.